# Elements.xml not setting document title property

Tags: document-library, elements-xml

I am writing a custom app to interact with a document library.
During deployment I have a module to populate the document library with some sample data, however I am not able to populate the Title field for each document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="DemoCVs" Url="Lists/CVs">
    <File Path="DemoCVs\Jane Doe CV.docx" Url="Jane Doe CV.docx" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
      <Property Name="Title" Value="Jane Doe" Type="string" />
    </File>
    <File Path="DemoCVs\John Smith CV.docx" Url="John Smith CV.docx" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
      <Property Name="Title" Value="John Smith" Type="string" />
    </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

The documents are successfully uploaded to the library, but the title field is always empty.

If I alter the file attribute to include Name like so

```
<File Path="DemoCVs\Jane Doe CV.docx" Url="Jane Doe CV.docx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Name="Jane Doe">
```

The title is set, however the document name loses its extention.
Setting the extension as such

```
<File Path="DemoCVs\Jane Doe CV.docx" Url="Jane Doe CV.docx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Name="Jane Doe CV.docx">
```

Makes the title property empty again.

Is this not the correct method, or have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You can add properties using declarative approach only if you add list items into Custom List, not when you add into Document Library.

I recommend adding sample files programmatically.

Or you can add files in XML and then add properties through code. I'd select the first option.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am not really certain how I would achieve this with a SPHosted App. The lists are instances within the app.

I tried running a post-build powershell script but there seems to be no way to pass this script the app-url.